# Analytic automorphisms of $n-$disk that fix the origin

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let's write an analytic surjection $f\colon D^n\longrightarrow D^n$ that fixes the origin $f(0)=0$, where $D^n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon|x|\leq1\}$. Is it possible that $f$ is *not* an open map?

Rephrased, is an analytic surjection from $D^n$ to itself with $f(0)=0$ necessarily an open map?

Comment: No. You can find a polynomial counterexample for $n=1$, etc.

Comment: And what if the map $f$ is homogeneous?

Comment: It well known that analytic (read: holomorphic) maps are open on the complex plane. Does writing it as $\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$ change that?